# React JS display the data after submitting

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Following is my react code which accepts the json format data and prints

```
          var DataInTableFormat = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function() {
                    return {
                      phpData: [] //initial value 
                    };//getInitialState
                },//DataInTableFormat 
                componentDidMount: function() {
                    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) { //storing the JSON data in result
                      var collection = JSON.parse(result);  //coverting JSON data to Javascript object
                      console.log(collection);
                      if (this.isMounted()) {//checking for component mount
                        this.setState({
                          phpData: collection

                       });
                      }
                    }.bind(this));
                },

                   render:function()
                    {

                      DBdata = this.state.phpData || [];
                        return (
                        <form>
                        <div>Select ID :
                          <select>
                          {DBdata.map(function(d){
                            return(
                                    <option value={d.id}>{d.id}</option>//prints the all id from the jsondata.php
                                   )}
                          )}
                          </select>
                        <button name="submit">submit</button>
                       </div> 
                       </form>
                )}
          });
          React.render(
            <DataInTableFormat source="http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/jsondata.php" />,
              document.getElementById('Table-data')
            );
```

When I select the ID I just want to print the all details in a table format after clicking on submit.

Comment: You want to print the data depends on the ID you selected?

Comment: @bignose Yes..I want to print data depends on ID I selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Define an `onChange` handler on the `<select>` element.

   ```
   <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
   ```
2. Add the event handler to your component definition, and use it to change the state of the component instance.

   ```
   handleChange: function (event) {
       this.setState({
           currentId: event.target.value
       });
   }
   ```
3. Use that piece of state in the `render()` method.

   ```
   render: function () {

       var currentId = this.state.currentId;
       var phpData = this.state.phpData || [];
       var selected = phpData.filter(function (item) {
           return item.id === currentId;
       });

       if (selected.length > 0) {
           // return stuff relating to selected[0]
       }
   ```

Comment: getting this error:ReferenceError: currentId is not defined
phpData: collection

Comment: After selecting the option @david

Comment: Put `currentId: null` in your `getInitialState` object.

Comment: Yeah I did and make my code like  submit : function(){
var currentId = this.state.currentId;
 console.log(currentId);
var phpData = this.state.phpData || [];
 console.log(phpData);
var selected = phpData.filter(function (item) {
 return item.id === currentId;
                           });
                          if(selected.length > 0){
                            return(
                                <input type="text" name="name" value={selected[1]}/>); }},

Comment: Is this right? Where can I render ? I want to print the all data in input text

Comment: Render everything related to `selected` inside the if block. You presumably want to show more than just the input field.